# Ulamog, the ceaseless hunger and strionic resonator combo

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's assume [Ulamog, the Ceaseless Hunger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUlamog%2c%20the%20Ceaseless%20Hunger%5d)'s ability gets copied to a differently named card. When Ulamog is the only attacking creature, will the total number of exiled cards be 20 or 40? Because of the triggered ability of [Strionic Resonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStrionic%20Resonator%5d)?

Comment: Are you asking 2 different questions here? One about copying Ulamog's abilities to a different creature, and one about Ulamog and Strionic Resonator?

Comment: @Hackworth I assume there's a misunderstanding about how the copying is applied through the Resonator.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to misunderstand how [Strionic Resonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStrionic%20Resonator%5d) works. Whenever a source you control has an ability that triggers, this ability is placed on the stack. You can react to this by activating the Resonator and copy the effect on the stack. When you placed the first effect on the stack (say, for instance "Whenever >name-a-card< attacks, tap target creature") you chose a creature to tap. With the Resonator, when you copy this effect, you can choose another target creature to tap. The Resonator **does not copy the text of the ability onto another creature**. Using  the Resonator, you can't copy a triggered ability from one creature to another, you can only interact with an effect on the stack that has a triggered ability as its source.

Then, using the Resonator on [Ulamog, the Ceaseless Hunger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUlamog%2c%20the%20Ceaseless%20Hunger%5d): You can copy both abilities with the Resonator and both of the effects will be applied twice. The line abount 'choosing new targets' on the Resonator is only relevant for the 'when cast'-trigger, the 'when it attacks'-trigger does not target.

Finally, if a card's ability refers to itself by name at any point, that's a shortcut for "this card/object"; it doesn't refer to other cards with the same name. So if you have two copies of [Basking Rootwalla](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBasking%20Rootwalla%5d), and you activate its pump on one of them, it only affects that one Basking Rootwalla.

Comment: Just for clarification based on the OP's implied combo: After attacking with Ulamog and then activating Strionic Resonator (and the Resonator resolving), there would be two separate "Exile the top 20 cards of defender's deck" effects on the stack, correct?

Comment: @DavidCEllis Yes, that's right. I've tried to convey that in my answer with  "You can copy both abilities with the Resonator and both of the effects will be applied twice." - Is this sentence formulated unclearly?

Comment: No, it is clear now, I just wanted to make sure I understood the resulting stack correctly. Thank you!